# Polynomial has real roots

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots, cubics, discriminant

I am trying to prove that the polynomial $f = X^3+pX+q \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ has three real roots iff $\Delta(f) = -(4p^3+27q^2) \geq 0$. I've figured out the left-to-right direction. Write $f = (X-\alpha_1)(X-\alpha_2)(X-\alpha_3)$, and then notice that
$$
\Delta(f) = (\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)^2(\alpha_1-\alpha_3)^2(\alpha_2-\alpha_3)^2 \geq 0. 
$$
But does anyone have a hint for the other direction? Suppose the discriminant is $\geq 0$, how to prove $f$ has three real roots (not necessarily distinct)?

Comment: Assume it doesn't have three real roots, so that two are complex conjugates and the other is real. Compute the discriminant and show that it is negative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's the alternative? Well, your polynomial can have one real root $\alpha_1$ and two non-real conjugate roots $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3=\overline{\alpha_2}$. Therefore\begin{align}(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2(\alpha_1-\alpha_3)^2(\alpha_2-\alpha_3)^2&=(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2\left(\alpha_1-\overline{\alpha_2}\right)^2\left(\alpha_2-\overline{\alpha_2}\right)^2\\&=\left|\alpha_1-\alpha_2\right|^4(2i\operatorname{Im}(\alpha_2))^2\\&=-4\left|\alpha_1-\alpha_2\right|^4(\operatorname{Im}(\alpha_2))^2\\&<0.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering what exactly is $Im(\alpha_2)$ and how you get so quickly to this? Is it just working out all the brackets or is there a trick?

Comment: @Sigurd $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha_2)$ is the imaginary part of $\alpha_2$. If $\alpha_2=a+bi$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb R$), then $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha_2)=b$. On the other hand$$\alpha_2-\overline{\alpha_2}=a+bi-(a-bi)=2bi=2i\operatorname{Im}(\alpha_2).$$

Answer (score 8):

Since $$-4p^3\geq27q^2,$$ we obtain $p\leq0.$

Now, $f'(X)=3X^2+p$, which gives $$X_{max}=-\sqrt{\frac{-p}{3}},$$$$X_{min}=\sqrt{\frac{-p}{3}}$$ and our equation has three real roots iff
$$f\left(X_{min}\right)f\left(X_{max}\right)\leq0,$$
which gives $$-4p^3-27q^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Could you  please explain why the equation has three real roots iff $f(X_{min}) f(X_{max}) \leq 0$?

Comment: @Sigurd Because we need three real roots. Draw it! If $f(X_{min})$ and $f(X_{min})$ have the same sing, so the polynomial has unique real root. Draw it again.

Comment: Nice suggestion, now it is clearer, thanks!

Comment: @Sigurd 1 You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Try to prove that if $f$ has a repeated root then $\Delta(f) = 0$ and if there are complex roots, then they appear in paris and then we must have that $\Delta(f) < 0$. Then as we have exhausted all cases we can establish the other side of the iff statement.